# Take the sum of every N rows in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose

`s = pd.Series(range(50))`

```
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
...
48     48
49     49
```

How can I get the new series that consists of sum of every n rows?

Expected result is like below, when n = 5;

```
0      10
1      35
2      60
3      85
...
8      210
9      235
```

If using loc or iloc and loop by python, of course it can be accomplished, however I believe it could be done simply in Pandas way.

Also, this is a very simplified example, I don't expect the explanation of the sequences:). Actual data series I'm trying has the time index and the the number of events occurred in every second as the values.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### `GroupBy.sum`

```
N = 5
s.groupby(s.index // N).sum()
     
0     10
1     35
2     60
3     85
4    110
5    135
6    160
7    185
8    210
9    235
dtype: int64
```

Chunk the index into groups of 5 and group accordingly.

---

#### `numpy.reshape` + `sum`

If the size is a multiple of N (or 5), you can reshape and add:

```
s.values.reshape(-1, N).sum(1)
# array([ 10,  35,  60,  85, 110, 135, 160, 185, 210, 235])
```

---

#### `numpy.add.at`

```
b = np.zeros(len(s) // N)
np.add.at(b, s.index // N, s.values)
b
# array([ 10.,  35.,  60.,  85., 110., 135., 160., 185., 210., 235.])
```

Comment: if i want to sum every 7 rows, do i use `7*7` then?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions yup!

Comment: I'm wondering if for performance isn't better to take the array as s.values and apply a numpy solution.

Comment: @user32185 Perhaps, but since OP did not mention performance, I've given OP the simplest solution I could think of.

Comment: @coldspeed it was just a remark. Your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user32185 Sure! No offence taken. And I've also added a numpy solution, since I'm pretty sure that would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient solution I can think of is `f1()` in my example below. It is orders of magnitude faster than using the `groupby` in the other answer.
Note that f1() doesn't work when the length of the array is not an exact multiple, e.g. if you want to sum a 3-item array every 2 items.
For those cases, you can use f1v2():

```
f1v2( [0,1,2,3,4] ,2 ) = [1,5,4]
```

My code is below. I have used `timeit` for the comparisons:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def f1(a,x):
    if isinstance(a, pd.Series):
        a = a.to_numpy()
    return a.reshape((int(a.shape[0]/x), int(x) )).sum(1)

def f2(myarray, x):
  return [sum(myarray[n: n+x]) for n in range(0, len(myarray), x)]

def f3(myarray, x):
    s = pd.Series(myarray)
    out = s.groupby(s.index // 2).sum()
    return out

def f1v2(a,x):
    if isinstance(a, pd.Series):
        a = a.to_numpy()
        
    mod = a.shape[0] % x
    if  mod != 0:
        excl = a[-mod:]
        keep = a[: len(a) - mod]
        out = keep.reshape((int(keep.shape[0]/x), int(x) )).sum(1)
        out = np.hstack( (excl.sum() , out) ) 
    else:       
        out = a.reshape((int(a.shape[0]/x), int(x) )).sum(1)
    
    return out
    

a = np.arange(0,1e6)

out1 = f1(a,2)
out2 = f2(a,2)
out3 = f2(a,2)

t1 = timeit.Timer( "f1(a,2)" , globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = 5, number = 2)
t1v2 = timeit.Timer( "f1v2(a,2)" , globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = 5, number = 2)
t2 = timeit.Timer( "f2(a,2)" , globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = 5, number = 2)
t3 = timeit.Timer( "f3(a,2)" , globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = 5, number = 2)

resdf = pd.DataFrame(index = ['min time'])
resdf['f1'] = [min(t1)]
resdf['f1v2'] = [min(t1v2)]
resdf['f2'] = [min(t2)]
resdf['f3'] = [min(t3)]
#the docs explain why it makes more sense to take the min than the avg
resdf = resdf.transpose()
resdf['% difference vs fastes'] = (resdf /resdf.min() - 1) * 100

b = np.array( [0,1,2,4,5,6,7] )

out1v2 = f1v2(b,2)
```

Comment: `The docs explain why it makes more sense to take the min than the avg` -- where is the docs? It's an interesting take. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html "higher values in the result vector are typically not caused by variability in Python’s speed, but by other processes interfering with your timing accuracy. So the min() of the result is probably the only number you should be interested in."