# how to subsequently aggregate the value in time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Apologies for the topic as I am not sure of the right way to describe my doubt in a single sentence. I have a dataframe which looks like below:

```
date       numbers
1/1/2019   5
2/1/2019   3
3/1/2019   6
4/1/2019   3
5/1/2019   1
6/1/2019   4
```

I wanted to aggregate with specified intervals (includes overlapping) 
The final dataframe should look like this:
for n = 2

```
date      numbers   
2/1/2019  8       (sum of 1/1/2019 and 2/1/2019)  
3/1/2019  9       (sum of 2/1/2019 and 3/1/2019) 
4/1/2019  9       (sum of 3/1/2019 and 4/1/2019)
5/1/2019  4
6/1/2019  5
```

What I tried is from the link [Take the sum of every N rows in a pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series?rq=1) 
But the problem is the sums are (1/1/2019 and 2/1/2019), (3/1/2019,4/1/2019), (5/1/2019 and 6/1/2019) and it is not overlapping.

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `rolling`

```
df.set_index('date').rolling(2).sum()
            numbers
date               
2019-01-01      NaN
2019-02-01      8.0
2019-03-01      9.0
2019-04-01      9.0
2019-05-01      4.0
2019-06-01      5.0
```