# Creating an Annual Sum Column from Quarterly / Monthly Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have quarterly or monthly data in Pandas and I want to find the annual sum. What's the most efficient way to do that?

For instance, let's say I have Quarter and Value and I want to create a new column "YearSum" that sums up the most recent 4 values.

```
Quarter, Value, YearSum
1, 2, null
2, 2, null
3, 3, null
4, 3, 10
5, 4, 12
6, 4, 14
7, 5, 16
8, 5, 18
```

I know I can do that by manually adding the totals like this:

```
df['YearSum'] = df.Value.shift(3) + df.Value.shift(2) + df.Value.shift(1) + df.Value
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `df.rolling(4,4)['Value'].sum()`

Answer (score 1):

`df['YearSum'] = df['Value'].rolling(min_periods=4, window=4).sum()`

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` to sum every x rows:

```py
result_series = df["Value"].groupby(df.index // 4).sum()
```

It will create a series where every value is the sum of 4 rows, means the sum over all quarters in a year (assuming your 4-align well, not starting from Q3 for example).

Edit: I found [Take the sum of every N rows in a pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series)
 which does the same as well suggesting another options.
Edit2: Notice it takes only exclusive 4-rows. means it takes 1-2-3-4 and then 5-6-7-8, not 2-3-4-5 after the first sum. Not sure what you wanted to do