# Pandas: sum every N amount of rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
      Date                  HomeTeam         OpponentTeam          Team_1 Goals
0     2020-05-01            Team_1              Team_2                 0
1     2020-05-02            Team_2              Team_1                 3
2     2020-05-03            Team_1              Team_3                 1
3     2020-05-04            Team_5              Team_1                 2
4     2020-05-05            Team_1              Team_2                 2
5     2020-05-06            Team_1              Team_4                 1
```

I need to calculate the sum of `Team_1 Goals` **for every 40 games**, not just for all of them. Beware that DataFrame contains games without `Team_1`, those should be ignored. Then I need to draw a plot to show how these sums change each year (`Team_1` has always more than 40 games per year). I have tried:

```
df["GoalSum"] = df[((df["HomeTeam"] == "Team_1") | (df["OpponentTeam"] == "Team_1")) & (df["Team_1 Goals"] != -1)].dropna()[:40].sum()["Team_1 Goals"]
plt.plot(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year, df["GoalSum"])
plt.show()
```

But this unfortunately calculates the sum of all `Team_1 Goals` so the plot is a straight line. How do I sum `Team_1` goals for every 40 games? As always, any advise is highly appreciated.

Edit: Expected output would be (if we wanted to sum every 3 games):

```
      Date                  HomeTeam         OpponentTeam          Team_1 Goals        GoalSum
0     2020-05-01            Team_1              Team_2                 0
1     2020-05-02            Team_2              Team_1                 3
2     2020-05-03            Team_1              Team_3                 1                  4
3     2020-05-04            Team_5              Team_1                 2
4     2020-05-05            Team_1              Team_2                 2
5     2020-05-06            Team_1              Team_4                 1                  5
```

Expected plot would look like:

[image]

Comment: could you please post sample of expected output in your question, for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Question updated.

Comment: Can you please either update your first dataframe as well, or remove it entirely. It is now confusing, as your question reads "how to go from the first dataframe to the second", which is not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take the sum of every N rows in a pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series). It is for a Series, but the same principle applies: group by n rows (thus *not* by a specific combination of columns), then sum those groups. You mean need to do some extra work to get the result back into the same dataframe.

Comment: I tried to show how original DataFrame differs from expected one.

Comment: Yes, but the two dataframes should at least be the same as to the input. So I think the first one requires three extra rows. Otherwise, there are magically three rows added, with a team 4 and team 5 that come out of nowhere.

Comment: @00 The answer in thread you linked uses GroupBy, I can't figure out by what column to groupby in this case.

Comment: Read the linked answer more carefully: they group by the index, divided by the group size (forty in your case). Your index is also a nicely monotically increasing set of integers, so this can work.

Comment: But my DataFrame does contain games where Team_1 is not playing, so that wouldn't work, unless I could first filter out those games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined your source DataFrame with some "additional" rows concerning
games without *Team_1* participation:

```
         Date HomeTeam OpponentTeam  Team_1 Goals
0  2020-05-01   Team_1       Team_2             0
1  2020-05-02   Team_2       Team_1             3
2  2020-05-03   Team_1       Team_3             1
3  2020-05-03   Team_4       Team_2             -1
4  2020-05-04   Team_5       Team_1             2
5  2020-05-05   Team_1       Team_2             2
6  2020-05-06   Team_1       Team_4             1
7  2020-05-06   Team_2       Team_3             -1
```

From your code sample I deduced that rows without *Team_1* have
value of *Team_1 Goals* set to just *-1*, but actually these
rows will not take part in the summation.

The first step is to generate a temporary DataFrame, limited to
games with *Team_1*:

```
dfLim = df.query("HomeTeam == 'Team_1' or OpponentTeam == 'Team_1'")
```

Assume that your group size is *3* just like in your example:

```
gSize = 3
```

To generate sum for each group, define the following function:

```
def mySum(grp):
    return pd.Series([grp['Team_1 Goals'].sum()], index=[grp.index[-1]])
```

And to add the new column, with these sums, run:

```
df['GoalSum'] = dfLim.groupby(np.arange(len(dfLim.index)) // gSize, group_keys=False)\
    .apply(mySum)
df.fillna(' ', inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
         Date HomeTeam OpponentTeam  Team_1 Goals GoalSum
0  2020-05-01   Team_1       Team_2             0        
1  2020-05-02   Team_2       Team_1             3        
2  2020-05-03   Team_1       Team_3             1       4
3  2020-05-03   Team_4       Team_2            -1        
4  2020-05-04   Team_5       Team_1             2        
5  2020-05-05   Team_1       Team_2             2        
6  2020-05-06   Team_1       Team_4             1       5
7  2020-05-06   Team_2       Team_3            -1
```