# Find sum of values of a column spread over different months in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks like

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 9 | 65 |
| 2017 | 10 | 72 |
| 2017 | 11 | 88 |
| 2017 | 12 | 97 |
| 2018 | 1 | 85 |
| 2018 | 2 | 67 |
| 2018 | 3 | 76 |
| 2018 | 4 | 51 |
| 2018 | 5 | 69 |
| 2018 | 6 | 97 |
| 2018 | 7 | 101 |
| 2018 | 8 | 22 |
| 2019 | 1 | 56 |
| 2019 | 2 | 34 |
| 2019 | 3 | 71 |
| 2019 | 4 | 122 |
| 2019 | 5 | 167 |
| 2019 | 6 | 34 |
| 2019 | 7 | 17 |
| 2019 | 8 | 99 |
| 2019 | 9 | 20 |
| 2019 | 10 | 26 |
| 2019 | 11 | 39 |
| 2019 | 12 | 30 |
| 2020 | 1 | 56 |
| 2020 | 2 | 34 |
| 2020 | 3 | 71 |
| 2020 | 4 | 122 |
| 2020 | 5 | 167 |
| 2020 | 6 | 34 |
| 2020 | 7 | 17 |
| 2020 | 8 | 99 |
| 2020 | 9 | 20 |
| 2020 | 10 | 26 |
| 2020 | 11 | 39 |
| 2020 | 12 | 30 |
| 2021 | 1 | 56 |
| 2021 | 2 | 34 |
| 2021 | 3 | 71 |
| 2021 | 4 | 122 |
| 2021 | 5 | 167 |
| 2021 | 6 | 34 |
| 2021 | 7 | 17 |
| 2021 | 8 | 99 |
| 2021 | 9 | 20 |
| 2021 | 10 | 26 |
| 2021 | 11 | 39 |
| 2021 | 12 | 30 |

Now what I want is :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 9 | 65 | 890 |
| 2017 | 10 | 72 | 890 |
| 2017 | 11 | 88 | 890 |
| 2017 | 12 | 97 | 890 |
| 2018 | 1 | 85 | 890 |
| 2018 | 2 | 67 | 890 |
| 2018 | 3 | 76 | 890 |
| 2018 | 4 | 51 | 890 |
| 2018 | 5 | 69 | 890 |
| 2018 | 6 | 97 | 890 |
| 2018 | 7 | 101 | 890 |
| 2018 | 8 | 22 | 890 |
| 2019 | 1 | 56 | 715 |
| 2019 | 2 | 34 | 715 |
| 2019 | 3 | 71 | 715 |
| 2019 | 4 | 122 | 715 |
| 2019 | 5 | 167 | 715 |
| 2019 | 6 | 34 | 715 |
| 2019 | 7 | 17 | 715 |
| 2019 | 8 | 99 | 715 |
| 2019 | 9 | 20 | 715 |
| 2019 | 10 | 26 | 715 |
| 2019 | 11 | 39 | 715 |
| 2019 | 12 | 30 | 715 |
| 2020 | 1 | 56 | 715 |
| 2020 | 2 | 34 | 715 |
| 2020 | 3 | 71 | 715 |
| 2020 | 4 | 122 | 715 |
| 2020 | 5 | 167 | 715 |
| 2020 | 6 | 34 | 715 |
| 2020 | 7 | 17 | 715 |
| 2020 | 8 | 99 | 715 |
| 2020 | 9 | 20 | 715 |
| 2020 | 10 | 26 | 715 |
| 2020 | 11 | 39 | 715 |
| 2020 | 12 | 30 | 715 |
| 2021 | 1 | 56 | 715 |
| 2021 | 2 | 34 | 715 |
| 2021 | 3 | 71 | 715 |
| 2021 | 4 | 122 | 715 |
| 2021 | 5 | 167 | 715 |
| 2021 | 6 | 34 | 715 |
| 2021 | 7 | 17 | 715 |
| 2021 | 8 | 99 | 715 |
| 2021 | 9 | 20 | 715 |
| 2021 | 10 | 26 | 715 |
| 2021 | 11 | 39 | 715 |
| 2021 | 12 | 30 | 715 |

Here 890 is the sum of all the values from 9,2017 through 8,2018 and 715 is the sum of all values from 1,2019 through 12,2019 and similarly 715 is the sum of all values from 1,2020 through 12,2020 and similarly 715 is the sum of all values from 1,2021 through 12,2021. For ease of calculation the numbers in column C have been taken the same i.e, (56,34,71,122,167,34,17,99,20,26,39,30) for each of 2019, 2020 and 2021. These numbers may vary for each of the years and subsequently their sums. That is we could have values like (67,87,99,100,76,11,23,44,56,78,87,5) for 2020 and (12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23) for 2021 for the months (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,10,11,12) subsequently.

Now my efforts:

```
count_months_in_each_year = data.groupby('CALENDAR_YEAR').agg({'CALMONTH':'count'})

count_months_in_each_year.reset_index(inplace = True)

count_months_in_each_year.rename({'CALMONTH':'Count_of_Months'}, axis =1, inplace = True)

data = pd.merge(data, count_months_in_each_year, on = 'CALENDAR_YEAR', how = 'left', indicator = True )

data.drop(columns = ['_merge'], axis =1 , inplace = True)
```

Now how to get the sum of the values especially in case when I have to consider 9,2017 through 8,2018 although I have the count.
Now based on this what logic can be driven to generalize the code in order to get the result.

I also tried this :

```
####Compute total number of records - number of records which have count of months < 12

number_ofless_than_12_records =  data.shape[0] - data[data['Count_of_Months']==12].shape[0]

#number_ofless_than_12_records = 144.
#Total records = 576
```

Can we make use of this somehow?

Comment: Are you always grouping 12 months regardless of the start/end month? What happens if you are missing 12/2019, do you sum from 1/2019 to 1/2020?

Comment: Yes in a way , yes, even if it starts from let's say 10,2017 it has to end at 9,2018. If I am missing 12/2019, I will be taking from 1/2019 through 1/2020 . Yes.

Comment: not 10/2017 to 1/2019?  there is no 9/2018.   I try to understand whether you are grouping with row indexes (12 group regardless of date) or fixed date (12 months from 1/2018-12/2018, 1/2019-12/2019).

Comment: No it was the there in the original data, but that had to be gotten rid of owing to making it a full calendar year from 9/2017 through 8/2018. Although it was there.

Comment: 12 group regardless of date, it can be anything that is the start and end date can be anywhere.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47239367/2956135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is making groups of 12 rows and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with the group sum:

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(df.index // 12)['C'].transform('sum')
```

```
       A   B    C    D
0   2017   9   65  890
1   2017  10   72  890
2   2017  11   88  890
3   2017  12   97  890
4   2018   1   85  890
5   2018   2   67  890
6   2018   3   76  890
7   2018   4   51  890
8   2018   5   69  890
9   2018   6   97  890
10  2018   7  101  890
11  2018   8   22  890
12  2019   1   56  715
13  2019   2   34  715
14  2019   3   71  715
15  2019   4  122  715
16  2019   5  167  715
17  2019   6   34  715
18  2019   7   17  715
19  2019   8   99  715
20  2019   9   20  715
21  2019  10   26  715
22  2019  11   39  715
23  2019  12   30  715
24  2020   1   56  715
25  2020   2   34  715
26  2020   3   71  715
27  2020   4  122  715
28  2020   5  167  715
29  2020   6   34  715
30  2020   7   17  715
31  2020   8   99  715
32  2020   9   20  715
33  2020  10   26  715
34  2020  11   39  715
35  2020  12   30  715
36  2021   1   56  715
37  2021   2   34  715
38  2021   3   71  715
39  2021   4  122  715
40  2021   5  167  715
41  2021   6   34  715
42  2021   7   17  715
43  2021   8   99  715
44  2021   9   20  715
45  2021  10   26  715
46  2021  11   39  715
47  2021  12   30  715
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this enlightening answer and the link #user2246849

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas rolling window function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html

```
df['D'] = df['C'].rolling(window=12).sum()
```

This will calculate the sum of the current month and 11 rows back. But it will fill with NaN values in the beginning, until there are enough months to look back.

So we can shift up 11 rows to get the wanted result.

```
df['D'] = df['D'].shift(-11)
```

And if you want don't want any NaNs at the end, you can interpolate or pad it out.

```
df['D'] = df['D'].interpolate()
```

Comment: Nope I get a different : ```5.59481e+06+6.58217e+06+5.23304e+06+5.23304e+06+5.01011e+06+4.4513e+06+5.43972e+06+6.63421e+06+7.93848e+06+6.53318e+06+7.37421e+06+6.82591e+06
Out[48]: 72850180.0```  Rolling sum gives me ```  Sum_of_Yearly_Sales
0 74042261.98
1 73305809.17999999
2 71592614.74
3 72168905.64
4 72355379.78
5 73991286.7
6 77799768.59
7 79127726.91800001
8 79313122.6053
9 77641996.1296
10 77515280.1371
11 75912701.7474
```

Comment: OP is not rolling.  I think groupby 12.  `groupby(df.index // 12).sum()`

Comment: Maybe. It's quite hard to understand exactly what OP wants.

Comment: No no apologies, it is not what I meant all I said was that I am in the favor of rolling sum but somehow it is not coming as expected. I beg my apologies.