# Calculate median values for every certain rows in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
})
```

I need to calculate median values for every `n` rows. Ideally, to write a function where I can pass `pd.Series` and `n` as arguments. So, if `n=2`, my function should return:

```
median
15
35
55
75
95
```

if `n=3`, then it should return:

```
median
20
50
80
100
```

In this example when `n=3`, the last returned value is `100`, however in my real dataset, I have a `df` with thousands of rows, and I want to set my `n` to `10` or `20`. So, as the last median value, it should return the median of `n%10`.

I included a similar function below just for reference from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series), it calculates the mean in the same manner I explained, but I need to tweak it to calculate the median.

```
def find_mean(col, rows):
    """
    col: pd.Series
    rows: number of rows 
    """
    if isinstance(col, pd.Series):
        col = col.to_numpy()
    mod = col.shape[0] % rows
    
    if  mod != 0:
        exclude = col[-mod:]
        keep = col[: len(col) - mod]
        out = keep.reshape((int(keep.shape[0]/rows), int(rows))).mean(1)
        out = np.hstack((out, exclude.mean())) 
    else:       
        out = col.reshape((int(col.shape[0]/rows), int(rows))).mean(1)
    return out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
N = 3
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N)['value'].median()
```

Output:

```
0     20
1     50
2     80
3    100
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, there was no need for all these code ))

Comment: Great approach never thought about it this way.