# Calculate sliding window median for Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is the follow-up question to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75663401/calculate-median-values-for-every-certain-rows-in-pandas-df)

So, I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'col2':[10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55],
                'col3':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']})
```

I would like to calculate the median values for `col1` and `col2` for every `'window'` rows. To do that I have the following function:

```
def calculate_median_val(df, window):
    return df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//window)['col1','col2'].median()
```

There are two problems with this function:

1. The returned `df` doesn't contain `col3`. I understand we can't calculate the median on strings, but how can I make sure it remains? The expected `df` is as follows:

if `window = 2`: The expected returned `df` is:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   1.5 12.5 A
1   3.5 22.5 A 
2   5.5 32.5 B
3   7.5 42.5 B
4   9.5 52.5 B
```

However, if `window=3`, then in `col3` second window, there will be `'A','B','B'`. Ideally, I would like to keep `'B'` as it is the majority, but it is not very critical right now, it can be `'A'` or `'B'`.

2. When I run the function above, it gives a future warning:

   FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.

I think this is due to passing more than 1 argument to calculate median values.

Comment: Can you provide the explicit output for `window=3`? Do you want the step median per group of col3? `N=3 ; df.groupby('col3').apply(lambda g: g.rolling(window=N).median().iloc[N-1::N])`?

Comment: @mozway thanks, the desired output is in the second part of solution by jezrael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with specify function for `col1` like [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'col2':[10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55],
                'col3':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']})

def calculate_median_val(df, window):
    return (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//window)
               .agg({'col1':'median', 'col2':'median', 'col3':'first'}))

print (calculate_median_val(df, 2))
   col1  col2 col3
0   1.5  12.5    A
1   3.5  22.5    A
2   5.5  32.5    B
3   7.5  42.5    B
4   9.5  52.5    B
```

If need prioritize `B` is possible create ordered categoricals and aggregate by `max`:

```
def calculate_median_val(df, window):
    df['col3'] = pd.Categorical(df['col3'], ordered=True, categories=['A','B'])
    return (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//window)
              .agg({'col1':'median', 'col2':'median', 'col3':'max'}))

print (calculate_median_val(df, 3))

   col1  col2 col3
0     2    15    A
1     5    30    B
2     8    45    B
3    10    55    B
```